# tar -xvf error "Can't restore time" when trying to extract in certain directories on mac osx but works in others

Tags: bash, tar

Strangest thing.

I downloaded the openjdk release here: https://jdk.java.net/16/

When running tar -xvf on the file in the ~/Downloads directory it works fine.

But when running in /tmp or another directory I have in my home folder I get the error: "Can't restore time"

Anybody seen this before?

Comment: Your clock is valid (not in the future) ? The /tmp is mounted on filesystem without precise time support like VFAT ?

Comment: It's a standard MacOs file system. Clock was valid.  It was a mystery.  I just ignored the error and everything has been working fine so far..